# Android Studio 0.8 Task assemble not found in root project

Tags: android, open-source, android-studio, iosched

I m trying to build the iosched app on ubuntu 14.04 on android studio 0.8 . After importing the setting.gradle file and following the build instruction I get an error saying

```
Error

    :FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Task 'assemble' not found in root project 'iosched'.

    * Try:
    Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21364895/android-studio-0-4-3-task-assemble-not-found-in-root-project) mentioned in this post doesn't work either.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're doing? I was able to import the iosched app and build it just fine in 0.8.6.

Comment: I m using android studio 0.8 , let me try building it with 0.8.6.

Comment: Previous error is gone but now I get this error "Error:Project 'android' not found in root project 'iosched'."

Answer (score 7):

Try to add this: `task assemble{}` in your root build.gradle file.

According to [this thread](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57229) it helps (it helped me as well).

Comment: just to expand it, the `task assemble {}` has to be in the build.gradle of every library, so for example in my library's build.gradle I would have the following content: `task assemble {}
configurations.create("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('slidingMenulibrary.aar'))`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was because my project implemented a Module that was an `android-library` (deprecated) / `com.android.library` which used a `minSdkVersion` lower than my project.
Be sure that your project and `android-library` / `com.android.library` have the same `minSdkVersion`.