# importing Opengl NDK into Android Studio

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I found a nice [example](http://code.google.com/p/android-native-egl-example/) with OpenGL for Android NDK. Then I tried to use it on Android Studio through the option import project. So, this is how the project files are distributed:

[image]

Then when I try to run it, it gives the message:

```
Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task '' not found in root project 'ndk3D'.

* Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

I went into: Run > Edit Configurations > Defaults > Android application > Additional command line options, and added: --stacktrace --info . On the same window, selected: Gradle > VM Options, and added: --stacktrace --info . Pressed: Apply OK. Then: Build > Make Project. The error message remains the same.

I couldn't also find a [component tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21364895/android-studio-0-4-3-task-assemble-not-found-in-root-project), should the problem be related to API version, so downgrading my API would solve it?

I also tried to import it into Eclipse and it didn't work either.

Any suggestion what might be missing? All comments are welcome.

Comment: The Android Studio page (http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) says "Coming Soon" for NDK support. So it doesn't look like it's supported yet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm absolute novice at using Android Studio but as an exercise to learn a bit of Gradle I did a simple port of android-native-egl-example from Ant to Gradle.  You can browse the project at https://github.com/tsaarni/android-native-egl-example/tree/gradle and compare to the master branch to see the changes.

To try it out, first go to console and navigate to `AndroidStudioProjects` directory and run `git clone -b gradle git@github.com:tsaarni/android-native-egl-example.git`.  Then launch Android Studio, choose "Open an existing Android Studio project" and select the newly cloned directory.   Set your SDK and NDK paths to `local.properties` file.