# Can anyone tell me how to import a project downloaded from associate android developer exam

Tags: android

I have downloaded an android project from associate android developer exam but not able to figure out how to import it in my android studio , can any one tell me the process for import. 
I have imported the project but in that project  i am not able to create any more java class or activity and also there are no suggestions showing while typing the code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import existing Android project into Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231474/how-to-import-existing-android-project-into-eclipse)

Comment: No, actually the problem i am facing is there are no suggestions showing while typing the code and i am not able to create new java and activity classes

Answer (score 0):

After downloading the zip file from  associate android developer exam website, extract the zip file, then open the Android Studio and import it.

Comment: No, actually the problem i am facing is there are no suggestions showing while typing the code and i am not able to create new java and activity classes

Comment: i did all the above steps

Comment: Its better to clean the project and rebuild it...if still it repeats....add the packages in build.gradle file---if you dont add the packages, you will be getting these type of errors

Comment: i am getting the error "Task assemble not found in root project add-color value" while cleaning the project

Comment: Check this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21364895/android-studio-0-4-3-task-assemble-not-found-in-root-project?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa]