# Task 'assemble' not found in root project

Tags: android

I am trying to import a project in android studio 3.1 but when I try to build the project it says "Task 'assemble' not found in root project". I searched for this error but didn't find straight forward answer and exist answers like  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21364895/android-studio-0-4-3-task-assemble-not-found-in-root-project) didn't work for me. any solution please?

[SOLVED]:
**The problem was because of missed settings.gradle file! just added it manually to the main project folder**

Comment: You should make that the accepted answer

Comment: i added settings.gradle and am still getting this error, so there's more to it than that

Answer (score 5):

Try this command in the terminal tab of android studio:

```
gradlew assembleDebug
```

Terminal tab can be found in the bottom panel, where you have Logcat.

Comment: try `gradle init` as well, it will install the missing dependencies.

Comment: same problem again! 'gradle' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: use `./gradlew init` instead

Comment: @Pitok it seems your system is not able to find gradle program, try declaring it in environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that settings.gradle file contains include ":app"