# Tasks aren't in the root project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

After importing [this project](https://github.com/mari-linhares/brick-blast-ball-RL) into Android Studios and I keep getting the error

```
Task 'assemble' not found in root project 'brick-blast-ball-RL-master'.
```

I've tried to fix this through the gradle and the build works in the .cmd terminal, but the build keeps failing due to the error above.

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21364895/android-studio-0-4-3-task-assemble-not-found-in-root-project) didn't resolve the problem, all facet have been removed.

What do I need to do to the code linked above to be able to run it on my cell phone?

gradle:

```
task assemble{

}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
   }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio 0.4.3 - Task 'assemble' not found in root project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21364895/android-studio-0-4-3-task-assemble-not-found-in-root-project)

Comment: i tried the solution to that problem without resolve

Comment: I also tried task assemble{} and the project builds, but the choice to "Run" is not able to be used.

Comment: post your `build.gradle` and `app/build.gradle`

Comment: @kimkarsh575 there might be two `*.iml` files.

Comment: It seems a simple problem. 1. Make a new project in Android Studio. 2. Copy and Paste the `manifest.xml`, `java files` and `res` into the correct places.(If you have other files, place them correctly too. I might help you out if I can do remote control with team viewer. This kind of errors occurs whenever you use open-source project files.

Comment: These files are python.

Comment: what needs to be done to this project so that i'll be able to run it on my mobile android device?